Header file in Adobe Acrobat SDK can't be found using sample code for plugin
So I downloaded the Adobe Acrobat SDK, looking to create my own plugin for Acrobat. I set the include path on Visual Studio to include the header files and added to the preprocessor definitions. However, I'm getting a fatal error when trying to run the Sample plugin program that comes with the SDK saying "PIHeaders.h: No such file or directory". I complied using gcc.exe and this is the latest SDK version for Windows (2021 v3).
Here is the line including the Header file that can't be found:
// Acrobat Headers.
#ifndef MAC_PLATFORM
#include "PIHeaders.h"
#endif

Here is what I get in the terminal when run:
Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -I C:\Users\dazzle\projects\FirstPlugin\Samples\BasicPlugin\sources\BasicPlugin.cpp -o C:\Users\dazzle\projects\FirstPlugin\Samples\BasicPlugin\sources\BasicPlugin.exe
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Picture of C++ file of the SDK sample and the error message
I was expecting for the program to compile and work out of the box. I didn't find any installation guide in the documentaion here:https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/plugin/index.html#about-plugins. I didn't see any Readme files in the SDK for the plugins. I made sure that the header file was included in the path, and I found the preprocessor definitions from the documentation online (WIN_PLATFORM, ACRO_SDK_PLUGIN, and WIN_ENV).
For those familiar with SDKs or the Adobe Acrobat SDK, is there an installation step I may have missed? What do you think it would be?
While I doubt it's the code, could this be caused by the header file? Am I doing something wrong at compilation?

Your -I in the compiler command line looks very odd. It should be -IFolderContainingTheHeaders not -I PathToExecutableName.exe

It's not an installation step you missed however you need to set the proper include directories in your build task in VSCode.

SO Usage Note: images of text (code, diagnostic, input, and output) are frowned on for many good reasons. Please present text as text.

@drescherjm Are you saying that's different from the Include Path for the project configurations? As in, I have to also include it in the tasks.json file for .vscode?

The "Include Path" in the c_cpp_properties.json does nothing at all for building. It's only for the Intellisense feature of the IDE. You need to specify your include path in tasks.json for building.

@drescherjm Alright, I added the headers to the tasks.json. Thank you, the fatal error is gone. I have a bunch of errors about undefined types. I think that's SDK related, but the #include "PIHeaders.h" still has an error saying PIHeaders.h: No such file or directory gcc.
